# Stop/continue a C program

Tags: c, signals

In my C program, I want to get the PID of the process, send a SIGSTOP to that and wait until a SIGCONT arrives from another terminal. So, the procedure looks like

```
int pid_t = getpid();
printf("PID %d has been stopped\n", pid_t);
STOP(pid_t);
while (not_received_CONT(pid_t))
   ;
// continue the program
```

How can I complete that?

Comment: Note that names ending `_t` are often type names, and `pid_t` specifically is the type for a PID.  While it works to use it as a variable name, it is not a good idea to use it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're writing doesn't make sense. When you stop the process, there is no more instructions being processed in the program and as such there is no `while` loop to wait for receiving the continuation.

If you check `man 7 signal` you can see that only one signal currently (in Linux) causes continuation of a process: `SIGCONT`, hence its not technically necessary to process a while loop check if you didn't get a continuation -- UNLESS you've got a situation where a number of signals are pending and you're trying to determine that.

You can rewrite your code implicitly to be:

```
int pid = getpid();
printf("PID %d has been stopped\n", pid);
kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
/* Process implicitly continues here, no while needed */
```

There are multiple vectors in Linux to manage signal handling which may not necessarily be portable.

There is the traditional `signal/sigaction` method of catching signals and invoking function calls on receipt of the signal. This can come with some unexpected caveats if you aren't careful.

Another way you can manage signals is the use of `sigwait`, you block the signal with `sigprocmask` and can consume signals in a safe fashion using `sigwait` to consume the signal at some controlled point in your process.

Finally you can do similar to `sigwait` with a `signalfd`. The main difference between it and `sigwait` being you can `poll` the FD to determine its readiness (a signal is received) then `read` the FD to consume the signals. This makes it a very nice way to manage signals in event driven programs.